# Javascript and Stylesheet in child page

Tags: functions, templates, javascript, wp-enqueue-style

I am trying figure out how to place JavasScript and stylesheet to parent page and children page via `functions.php`. The parent page is Our People and children page is staff names.

This is what I wrote:

### JavaScript

```
wp_register_script ('unslider-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/library/js/unslider-min.js', array( 'jquery' ),'1',false);

if ( is_page('our-people') && in_array( get_post_ancestors(597) ) ) { wp_enqueue_script ('unslider-js'); }
```

### Stylesheet

```
wp_register_style ('unslider-css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/library/css/unslider.css', array(),'', 'all');
if ( is_page() && in_array( get_post_ancestors(597) ) ) { wp_enqueue_style ('unslider-css'); }
```

It seem that it does not fetch these files for the parent and child page. Could anyone guide me how to achieve this approach?

Answer (score 0):

This code will check to make sure that the Our People page is being viewed (page with slug `our-people`) or one of the children of page with ID 597, and will enqueue both the JavaScript and CSS if so:

```
function wpse241030_scripts() {
    // Bail if we're not looking at the Our People page or one of the children of page with ID 597.
    if ( ! is_page( 'our-people' ) && ! in_array( 597, (array) get_post_ancestors( get_the_ID() ) ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Enqueue unslider JS
    wp_enqueue_script( 'unslider-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/library/js/unslider-min.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1', false );

    // Enqueue unslider CSS
    wp_enqueue_style( 'unslider-css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/library/css/unslider.css', array(), '', 'all' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse241030_scripts' );
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer Dave, but when I copied your codes to functions.php and refresh the our-people page or our-people/person-name does not fetch the files required. Whats the correct step to make your code work?

Comment: Sorry it's not working for you, William. I've just triple checked the code, and it's working for me; the `unslider-min.js` and `unslider.css` files files are enqueued on (and only on) the `our-people` page or its sub-pages.